# The command to add to path in Julia language

Tags: path, julia

How can I add a path to my current path in Julia, so that I can organize files and modules in folders, but still access them?

Comment: Are you just using `include()`? You can put full paths rather than just file names in the string passed to that function.

Comment: Actually I am using "using" to exploit a module.

Comment: I found the solution for modules: The global variable LOAD_PATH contains the directories Julia searches for modules when calling require. It can be extended using push!push!(LOAD_PATH, "/Path/To/My/Module/")

Comment: Stil I face problems not with "using", but  now with "import".

Comment: how about `DL_LOAD_PATH`?  If you're on 0.3 it should be `Base.Sys.DL_LOAD_PATH`.  If you're on 0.4 it moved to `Base.Libdl.DL_LOAD_PATH`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: the following paths may be Unix-specific.

You can add the file `.juliarc.jl` to your home directory, and include the line

```
@everywhere push!(LOAD_PATH,"/path/to/my/code")
```

The `@everywhere` ensures that it will work even if you've started julia with multiple workers.

Comment: It works, except that in 0.7 the startup file is now [`~/.julia/config/startup.jl`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/modules/#Module-file-paths-1)

Answer (score 1):

This is an updated and extended version of the answer by *tholy* and *ederag*. On Linux and Windows with Julia 1.0 one can add the folder `myproject/src` in the user homefolder to the Julia `LOAD_PATH` by adding

```
using Distributed
@everywhere push!(LOAD_PATH, joinpath(homedir(), "myproject", "src"))
```

to `<homedir>/julia/config/startup.jl`. For a fresh Julia install, `startup.jl` nor the folder `config` exists (on Linux at least). Just create the file and folder and Julia will read `startup.jl` automatically.

Comment: Thanks. For me (Julia 1.5.3 on Windows), this file was located in `<homedir>/julia/etc/startup.jl` and a blank copy was already created for me.